# Different result with DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, directorysearcher

I wrote a small app to check AD group members. When I execute the following code on my pc, It works well, the SearchResult contains the "member" property, however when I run the same exe on the server or on an another computer the "member" property is missing. The usnchanged and usncreated will be different also. I run the exe with the same user on every pc. What can cause this?

```
...
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher())
{
    searcher.CacheResults = false;
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=" + ADName + "))";
    searcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
    searcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;
    if (!DirectoryEntry.Exists(ADPath))
    {
        return null;
    }
    searcher.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(ADPath);
    using (SearchResultCollection collection = searcher.FindAll())
    {
        if (collection.Count == 1)
        {
            return collection[0];
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: And in ADPath you point to your active directory server?

Comment: ADPath is "GC://DC=DOMAIN,DC=COMPANY,DC=com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group membership data is not replicated to the global catalog. The query might work sometimes, if you happen to connect to the domain controller with the actual membership data. On other machines, you probably connect to other domain controllers, of different domains, where the information is not available.

You might want to connect to a domain controller in the actual domain, not to the global catalog.

Comment: You are right, if I specify the domain controller it's working well, so the ADPath will be "GC://Domain_Controller_IP/DC=DOMAIN,DC=COMPANY,DC=com". 
But how can I determine the right Domain controller, because on the server if I run the echo %LOGONSERVER% from cmd it will give different output than my local pc. And if I run it from another domain of course the controller will be different also.
The easy way is to hardcode the ip, but I don't want it.

Comment: You don't have to specify IP. You can use something like "LDAP://Domain_Controller_Address/DC=DOMAIN,DC=COMPANY,DC=com".

Comment: All right, new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DOMAIN).ConnectedServer contains the right address. Thank you for the quick support!